# How to assert a discriminated union is of a certain variant in typescript unit tests?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I was trying to write unit tests in typescript using jest.

```js
// This is how foo() is defined:
// function foo(): 
//        {status: "OK"} | 
          {status: "ERROR", reason: "INVALID_ID"|"SOME_OTHER_ERROR"};

let res = foo();
expect(res.status).toEqual("ERROR");
expect(res.reason).toEqual("INVALID_ID");
// ^^^ this line gives error TS2339: Property 'reason' does not exist on type ....
```

Does typescript have some construct like `assert(res.status == "ERROR")` after which the compiler can figure out that the result is of the second variant here?

If not, is there any other unit test framework that provides necessary hints to the compiler in its `expect()` like functions?

Or is there a better way to return error from `foo()`?

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you can just use a simple type assertions.

```
// Store the type for convenience.
type ErrorResponse = {status: "ERROR", reason: "INVALID_ID"|"SOME_OTHER_ERROR"}


let res = foo();
expect((res as ErrorResponse).reason).toEqual("INVALID_ID");
```

In more advanced scenarios you might want to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

```
type OkResponse = {status: "OK"}
type ErrorResponse = {status: "ERROR", reason: "INVALID_ID"|"SOME_OTHER_ERROR"};

function isErrorResponse(response: OkResponse | ErrorResponse): response is ErrorResponse {
  return response.status === "ERROR"
}
```